# Change user from bash to zsh on Dreamhost

Tags: bash, shell, zsh, dreamhost

I created a sudo user for my Dreamhost VPS and I left the defaults upon creation. This user now defaults to bash when I ssh in. I noticed that there is a dropdown to change the user to zsh when I edit the user using their admin panel, but the changes never stick -- it always reverts back to bash. Can I change a user to zsh through the panel or do I need to install zsh the old fashioned way? And if I install it the old fashioned way, are there any things to be careful of? I don't want to break anything.

Comment: Hey joe it's in `/etc/passwd` in the 7th column. But you break it and you can't login...

Comment: So what will happen if I change this line?
superman:x:1412:3:joe sepi:/home/superman:/bin/bash
to
superman:x:1412:3:joe sepi:/home/superman:/usr/bin/zsh
??

Maybe I should try it on a test user first. I'm a little scared. My ghost blog is running under this user.

Comment: joe sepi: that should work. Or see my answer for a better solution.

Comment: Thanks guys! I am all good now. Added oh-my-zsh as well with no troubles. Now I am *really* gonna do some stuff!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a unix command to change your shell - `chsh`.

```
chsh -s $(which zsh)
```

SSH in, run this - you will be prompted for a password. Your shell is now permanently changed. This will only disastrously break your machine if you have a seriously messed up zsh install, where `zsh` isn't actually zsh.